# MongoDB conditional update array elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose in a Node.js backend and I need to update a subset of elements of an array within a document based on a condition. I used to perform the operations using save(), like this:

```
const channel = await Channel.findById(id);
  channel.messages.forEach((i) =>
    i._id.toString() === messageId && i.views < channel.counter
      ? i.views++
      : null
  );
  await channel.save();
```

I'd like to change this code by using findByIdAndUpdate since it is only an increment and for my use case, there isn't the need of retrieving the document. Any suggestion on how I can perform the operation?

Of course, **channel.messages** is the array under discussion. **views** and **counter** are both of type Number.

**EDIT** - Example document:

```
{
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "61546b9c86a9fc19ac643924"
    },
    "counter": 0,
    "name": "#TEST",
    "messages": [{
        "views": 0,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61546bc386a9fc19ac64392e"
        },
        "body": "test",
        "sentDate": {
            "$date": "2021-09-29T13:36:03.092Z"
        }
    }, {
        "views": 0,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61546dc086a9fc19ac643934"
        },
        "body": "test",
        "sentDate": {
            "$date": "2021-09-29T13:44:32.382Z"
        }
    }],
    "date": {
        "$date": "2021-09-29T13:35:33.011Z"
    },
    "__v": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `updateOne` method if you don't want to retrieve document in result,

- match both fields `id` and `messageId` conditions
- check expression condition, `$filter` to iterate loop of `messages` array and check if `messageId` and `views` is less than `counter` then it will return result and `$ne` condition will check the result should not empty
- `$inc` to increment the `views` by 1 if query matches using `$` positional operator

```
messageId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(messageId);
await Channel.updateOne(
  {
    _id: id,
    "messages._id": messageId,
    $expr: {
      $ne: [
        {
          $filter: {
            input: "$messages",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$$this._id", messageId] },
                { $lt: ["$$this.views", "$counter"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        []
      ]
    }
  },
  { $inc: { "messages.$.views": 1 } }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tr97cEZ4Giq)